# How to implement Yosai Authentication and Authorisation in Django Project?

Tags: python, django, authentication, authorization, security-framework

I am trying to implement [Yosai](https://github.com/YosaiProject/yosai)- Security Framework for Python applications in django project following this [documentation](https://yosaiproject.github.io/yosai/).

The [Web Integration](https://yosaiproject.github.io/yosai/web/) page says,

> yosai.web is designed to integrate with any kind of web application.
> It can integrate with any application framework, such as Django,
> Pyramid, Flask, or Bottle. This is made possible through
> application-specific implementations of the WebRegistry API.

1.What is WebRegistry?

2.How can use **WebYosai** to implement Authentication and Other functionalities.

I have gone through the documentation but I could not understand the implementation.Any help would be greatly appreciated.